# PHP PDO MS SQL Server SELECT LIMIT

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am converting my project from MySQL based to MS SQL using PHP PDO, The below code allows to thread thought records (left and right)and if the record lets say #1 then it should stay on #1 same for the last record. I get error:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dxbase\DB_Project\private\supplierschoice.php on
>   line 96

Line 96 is where:

```
<?php echo "<input type='text' id='CSupplierCode' value='" . $row['SupplierCode'] . "'>"; ?>
```

I also have `$row = $result->fetch();` before that.

Code that runs on "LEFT" button:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT s.SupplierID, ..., l.StreetAddress, ... FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN Locations l ON s.SupplierID = l.RefID WHERE l.LocGroup = 1 AND s.SupplierID < '" . $tID . "' ORDER BY s.SupplierID DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
if (!$result) {
   $sql = "SELECT s.SupplierID, ..., l.StreetAddress, ... FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN Locations l ON s.SupplierID = l.RefID WHERE l.LocGroup = 1 AND s.SupplierID = '" . $tID . "'";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if (!$result) { echo "Error creating a record: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn -> errorInfo();}
}
?>
```

The code does NOT get to the second part (`!$result`), so it gives a warning and empty inputs.

UPDATE:
Tried to use SELECT TOP 1

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 s.SupplierID, s.SupplierCompany, s.SupplierCode, s.Currency, s.PaymentTerm, s.ShippingTerm, s.TMode, s.Agent, s.Carrier, s.Warehouse, l.StreetAddress, l.Suite, l.City, l.Locality, l.State, l.PostalCode, l.Country FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN Locations l ON s.SupplierID = l.RefID WHERE l.LocGroup = 1 AND s.SupplierID < '" . $tID . "' ORDER BY s.SupplierID DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        $sql = "SELECT s.SupplierID, s.SupplierCompany, s.SupplierCode, s.Currency, s.PaymentTerm, s.ShippingTerm, s.TMode, s.Agent, s.Carrier, s.Warehouse, l.StreetAddress, l.Suite, l.City, l.Locality, l.State, l.PostalCode, l.Country FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN Locations l ON s.SupplierID = l.RefID WHERE l.LocGroup = 1 AND s.SupplierID = '" . $tID . "'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if (!$result) { echo "Error creating a record: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn -> errorInfo();}
    }
```

it is still does not get to the 2nd part after ID less then #1 and it seems like (!$result) is not working here..

Comment: SQL Server does not have `LIMIT` keyword, so your statement is wrong.

Comment: Btw, you're still open to SQL injection. The prepare/execute you have without placeholders doesn't make it a true prepared statement.

Comment: Thank you Funk Forty Niner, for the advise, that will follow later, just need to make sure what I have is working

Comment: @MaxCB Use `SELECT TOP (1) ...` instead of `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: It seems like the $result is always TRUE here, even though ID less than #1 does not exist

Answer (score 1):

OK! After 100 trial and errors I got the following code working properly
for moving left and right in MS SQL Server

```
} elseif ($tID > 0 && $Order == 3) {
    $sql = "SELECT TOP 1 s.SupplierID, s.SupplierCompany, s.SupplierCode, s.Currency, s.PaymentTerm, s.ShippingTerm, s.TMode, s.Agent, s.Carrier, s.Warehouse, l.StreetAddress, l.Suite, l.City, l.Locality, l.State, l.PostalCode, l.Country FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN Locations l ON s.SupplierID = l.RefID WHERE l.LocGroup = 1 AND s.SupplierID < '" . $tID . "' ORDER BY s.SupplierID DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!$row) {
        $sql = "SELECT s.SupplierID, s.SupplierCompany, s.SupplierCode, s.Currency, s.PaymentTerm, s.ShippingTerm, s.TMode, s.Agent, s.Carrier, s.Warehouse, l.StreetAddress, l.Suite, l.City, l.Locality, l.State, l.PostalCode, l.Country FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN Locations l ON s.SupplierID = l.RefID WHERE l.LocGroup = 1 AND s.SupplierID = '" . $tID . "'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
} elseif ($tID > 0 && $Order == 7) {
    $sql = "SELECT TOP 1 s.SupplierID, s.SupplierCompany, s.SupplierCode, s.Currency, s.PaymentTerm, s.ShippingTerm, s.TMode, s.Agent, s.Carrier, s.Warehouse, l.StreetAddress, l.Suite, l.City, l.Locality, l.State, l.PostalCode, l.Country FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN Locations l ON s.SupplierID = l.RefID WHERE l.LocGroup = 1 AND s.SupplierID > '" . $tID . "' ORDER BY s.SupplierID ASC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!$row) {
        $sql = "SELECT s.SupplierID, s.SupplierCompany, s.SupplierCode, s.Currency, s.PaymentTerm, s.ShippingTerm, s.TMode, s.Agent, s.Carrier, s.Warehouse, l.StreetAddress, l.Suite, l.City, l.Locality, l.State, l.PostalCode, l.Country FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN Locations l ON s.SupplierID = l.RefID WHERE l.LocGroup = 1 AND s.SupplierID = '" . $tID . "'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```